# Why isn't a nasalised vowel used for "divin" here?

Tags: prononciation, phonétique, nasalisation

I was searching for some Christmas carols and decided to look up "Il est né le divin enfant", having heard only the beginning of the song in the past. I then noticed that all the recordings I listened to, including those by presumed native speakers, seem to have pronounced "divin" (*Il est né le divin enfant*) with something like /di.vin/. ([Here](https://youtu.be/g4cyWxevyAY?t=19s) is one example.)

This was odd to me, as the only other time I have heard "divin" pronounced was in a few recordings of Massenet's *Werther*. (*Jésus vient de naître, voici notre divin maître rois et bergers d'Israël!*) ([Example recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXekrmGs1ts).) In those recordings, I heard "divin" pronounced as /di.vɛ̃/, which is also the pronunciation reported on Wiktionary. (While the site is not always reliable, I would be inclined to trust it here.)

Why is there such a discrepancy? Does this reflect any broader pronunciation rules or tendencies, or can it be considered a one-off case? (Alternatively, perhaps something is wrong with my ears?)

Comment: Since "enfant" start with a vowel, there is a connection between "divin" and "enfant", so it is pronounced as if "divinenfant" was a word.

Answer (score 6):

You're right, it's not nasalized in *divin enfant* though it is in *divin maître*. Why? The latter is the normal pronunciation, but in the former, the e at the beginning of *enfant* requires that the n be pronounced in a [liaison](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/pronunciation/liaisons/).

Edited to add: When nasal vowels at the end of adjectives are subject to liaison, they essentially change to the feminine, non-nasal pronunciation. For e and o, this is easy. The nasal [ɑ̃] [ɔ̃] and non-nasal [a] [o] pronunciations of these two vowels are very similar - they don't "change shape," as ChrisW put it below.

But the i is special: the feminine, non-nasal pronunciation [i] is quite different than the nasal pronunciation [ɛ̃]. When in a liaison, *divin* [di vɛ̃] is pronounced like *divine* [di vin], *fin* [fɛ̃] is pronounced like *fine* [fin], etc

Comment: I was wondering if the word that followed had something to do with the nasalisation, but somehow did not catch onto this. (That I could not think of any good, appropriately similar "lines" elsewhere for comparison did not help.) This makes sense!

Comment: That explains why the `n` has a *liaison* but doesn't wholly explain why the `i` vowel changes shape. For example, the fact that the `n` has a *liaison* in "en Amérique" doesn't change the shape of the `e`, and ditto the shape of the `o` in "on a tort".

Comment: That's true, the nasal i is special: the pronunciation changes to the feminine, non-nasal pronuncation when they liaise. *Divin* is pronounced like *divine*, *fin* is pronounced like *fine*, etc.

Comment: @lkl: perhaps that could be added to the answer? It'd be nice to have a slightly "stronger" result, I suppose.

Comment: The change in vowel quality is rather complicated! The nasal vowel /ɛ̃/ has evolved a lot over the years. the spelling reflects an earlier pronunciation; divin used to be /divin/ and divine /divinə/. For the masculine form, the n dropped (except when "protected" by a vowel as in divin_enfant) and the i nasalized. Nasal i later became /ɛ̃/ which itself has moved considerably farther back in European French in the last century. Meanwhile the i in divin_enfant is still i.

Comment: @hunter Your comment is interesting, includes formatting, a link, please make an answer out of it so that someone can get the full picture in a single post! Thanks!

Comment: So [ɑ̃] is always denasalized to [a]? The pronunciation of "il leur en a donné" is something like '/i.lœ.ra.na.dɔ.ne/?

Answer (score 4):

En complément à une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/16525), il faut éviter de trop généraliser. Pour illustrer, il peut être utile de présenter brièvement la [différence](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3541) entre la *liaison* et l'*enchaînement* pour introduire l'idée de la *dénasalisation*, ou de la *décomposition* etc..

---

> (1) *le**s e**nfants* [le- zɑ ̃-fɑ ̃] [liaison]
>   (2) *à co**r** **e**t à cri* [ʌ-kɔ-ʀe-...] [enchaînement]
>   (3) *bel**le** **a**ffaire* [bε-lʌ-fεʀ] [enchaînement avec *e* muet suivant la consonne dans le mot]
>   (4) [liaison avec décomposition, dénasalisation...]
>  — *plei**n** **a**ir* [plε-nεʀ]
>  — *bo**n** **a**uteur* [bɔ-notœʀ]
>  — *divi**n** **e**nfant* [divi-nɑ ̃fɑ ̃]
>   (5) [liaison sans décomposition, dénasalisation]
>  — *[mali**n**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/malin) **e**sprit* [malε- nεspʀi] 
>  — *fi**n** **e**sprit* [fε- ̃nεspʀi]

1. *La liaison* a lieu quand la consonne finale est *muette*, devant un mot commençant par une *voyelle*
2. *L'enchaînement* se produit quand la consonne finale du mot est *articulée* avec le mot seul, et qu'elle l'est ici, devant un mot commençant par une *voyelle*
3. ...même quand la consonne précéde un *e* muet dans le mot
4. Les adjectifs qui se terminent par *-ain, -ein, -en, -on, -in* 
   emportent la dénasalisation de la voyelle, mais il faut en exclure
   *aucun, on, un<sup>1</sup>, commun, rien, bien, en*, où il n'y a *pas* dénasalisation, et *non*, où l'usage n'est *pas fixé*
5. Il peut y avoir liaison sans décomposition ou enchaînement. On ne
   peut passer sous silence le propos au *TLFi* à ce sujet :

> Comparez, dans la liaison, la prononc. de *malin esprit*, *fin
>   esprit*, [malε ̃nεspʀi], [fε ̃nεspʀi] avec celle de *divin Enfant*, le
>   *divin Achille*, *Homère*, *Ulysse*, le *divin amour* où il n'est plus d'usage de conserver la nasale : [divinɑ ̃fɑ ̃], [divinaʃil],
>   [-ɔmε:ʀ], [-ylis], [divinamu:ʀ]. Mart. ***Comment prononce*** 1913, p. 389,
>   explique la suppression de la nasale par la grande diffusion des
>   Cantiques de Noël qui a imposé [divinɑ ̃fɑ ̃]. Cette prononc. s'est
>   étendue, p. anal., à d'autres expr. formées à partir de *divin* du
>   type *divin Achille*, etc., sans que, pour autant, d'apr. Mart., *loc.
>   cit.*, il soit obligatoire d'aligner la prononc. de ces expr. sur
>   *divin Enfant*. [*Littré*](http://www.littre.org/definition/divin) se prononce pour la conservation de la nasale. Pour les expr. *malin esprit*, *fin esprit*, Mart., *loc. cit.*,
>   conseille, afin d'éviter le piège, de les inverser en esprit malin et
>   esprit fin mais n'en change-t-il pas en même temps le sens?
>
> [ *Trésor informatisé de la langue française* - TLFi, [divin](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/divin) ]
>
> ---
>
> Le cas des adjectifs en *-in* est plus délicat, car *-in* fait au féminin
>   -*ine*, qui ne correspond pas phonétiquement au masculin. Pourtant la grande diffusion des cantiques de Noël a répandu et imposé
>   l'expression *divi*-n*enfant*. Par analogie, on dira très correctement
>   *divi*-n*Achille*, *divi*-n*Ulysse*, *divi*-n*Homère* ; mais ici la décomposition de la nasale s'impose moins absolument, quoique la liaison soit
>   également indispensable. C'est d'ailleurs le seul adjectif en -in qui
>   puisse se décomposer : *malin esprit* ou *fin esprit* se lieront donc *au
>   besoin* sans décomposition; mais je pense qu'*esprit malin* et surtout
>   *esprit fin* vaudraient beaucoup mieux (1).
>
> [ [*Comment on prononce le français*](https://archive.org/stream/commentonprononc00martuoft#page/388/mode/2up): traité complet de prononciation
>   pratique avec les noms propres et les mots étrangers, [Philippe
>   Martinon](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippe_Martinon), 1913 chez Larousse, p. 389, note omise ]

---

Il y a *compétition* entre la liaison et l'enchaînement dans les cas où la consonne du mot est /r/, se prononce, et est suivie d'une consonne muette (*vers elle*) ; l'enchaînement [vε-ʀεl] l'*emporte* sur la liaison [vεʀ-zεl] dans ce cas ; il s'*impose* dans *corps à corps* [kɔ-ʀʌ-kɔʀ] ; mais si cette consonne muette indiquait le *nombre* grammatical, alors la liaison revient à la charge (*leurs enfants* [lœʀ- zɑ ̃-fɑ ̃] ; mais *porc épic* ([pɔʀ-kepik], sing et plur.), avec exceptions, évidemment, dont l'*s* intérieur des *locutions nominales* (*moulins à vent* ; on conclut généralement qu'il y a contradiction entre la prononciation et la règle traditionnelle du pluriel des noms composés) où la liaison serait *inusitée* (hormis les cas où il y a pause ou disjonction, comme avec le *h* aspiré et autres cas comme *les onze*). Et ainsi de suite...<sup>2</sup>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Les numéraux sont un cas particulier. Voir [*un*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/un) : [œ ̃], [yn]. L'un et l'autre [lœ ̃ne-] (*TLFi*). Au *LBU* (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. *Duculot*), au §591 c), on explique que *un* fait justement [œn ̃] quand il sert de déterminant à un nom débutant par une voyelle...</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Les points 1 à 4 ainsi que ce paragraphe paraphrasent des éléments sélectionnés parmi ceux apparaissant au *LBU* aux §§41-43, desquels sont aussi extraits la majorité des exemples. Il ne s'agit pas d'une analyse exhaustive. Le marquage phonétique peut manquer d'uniformité et/ou de rigueur ; il a surtout pour but d'illustrer le découpage, plus que de retranscrire avec exactitude.</sub>

Comment: Au moins 50 points à quiconque peut produire ou attester du la [partition originale](http://cantorion.org/music/4143/He-is-born,-the-divine-Child-%28Il-est-n%C3%A9,-le-divin-Enfant%29-Voice-Piano-Organ) de MM. _Grosjean_ ou chez Legeay, et indiquer si elle contient une indication sur la prononciation chantée du passage _divin enfant_ ; ou un élément prescriptif/descriptif du domaine religieux qui vient confirmer qu'on demandait de prononcer d'une manière ou d'une autre, sans doute selon la prononciation latine \diːˈwiː.nus\ ou vu un truc dans _La tête bizarde_. Merci !

Answer (score 3):

The denasalization before a word starting with a vowel like with *Divin enfant* only affects a limited set of adjectives, mostly ending with /ɛ̃/ although there is one in /ɔ̃/ and is often optional. These adjectives must precede the word they qualify which is not the usual order in French unlike English. The /ɛ̃/ becoming /in/ in "divin enfant" seems to be a unique case as normally, /ɛ̃/ is changed to /ɛn/.

- Ancien

> Mon ancien ami /mɔ̃n‿ɑ̃sjɛn‿ami/ or /mɔ̃n‿ɑ̃sjɛ̃n‿ami/

- Certain

> Un certain âge /sɛrtɛn‿aʒ/ or /sɛrtɛ̃n‿aʒ/

- Divin

> Divin enfant /divin‿ɑ̃fɑ̃/

but

> Divin Homère /divɛ̃.omer/ (always nasalization, no liaison)

- Moyen

> Moyen-âge /mwajɛn‿aʒ/ but more and more /mwajɛ̃n‿aʒ/

- Plein

> Plein air /plɛn‿ɛr/ or /plɛ̃n‿ɛr/

- Bon

> Bon appétit /bɔ.n‿a.pe.ti/ or /bɔ̃.n‿a.pe.ti/
>
> Bon homme -> Bonhomme /bɔ.n‿ɔm/ (never /bɔ̃.n‿ɔm/)

When the first word is another adjective or not an adjective at all, nasalization is maintained and there is often no liaison even with an adjective:

> Un fin orateur /fɛ̃.ɔʁatœʁ/ or /fɛ̃n‿ɔʁatœʁ/ but never /fin‿ɔʁatœʁ/
>
> Le marin arrive /maʁɛ̃.aʁiv/

Comment: I was wondering if the tendency to shift to /ɛn/ was simply a result of the fact that adjectives commonly involved (e.g. ancien) tend to presumably be pronounced as such in their feminine forms (which wouldn't be the case for adjectives with _-in_), but the "un fin orateur" example (assuming I'm parsing the phrase correctly) covers this well enough for me.

Comment: @Maroon I believe the difference is historical (as is accurately reflected by the spelling). "divin" was historically /divin/, and "prochain" /prɔʃɛn/. The /in/ in divin became /ĩ/ which later became /ɛ̃/, whereas the /ɛn/ in "prochain" went straight to /ɛ̃/.

Comment: for (way too much!) more information, see this nice table https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_French#Table_of_vowel_outcomes