# How are nasal vowels denasalized during liaison?

Tags: prononciation, liaisons, nasalisation

I already read this

[Why isn't a nasalised vowel used for "divin" here?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16437/why-isnt-a-nasalised-vowel-used-for-divin-here)

answer, but I felt like I needed a more complete answer.

I know that some nasal vowel at the end of words are denasalized during liaison (although sources seem to disagree on the exceptions), but I haven't been able to find out what the resulting vowel is. What are the rules?

For example, are the examples of words ending in "-un" or "-um" /œ̃/ that denasalize during liaison, and if so, would the resulting vowel be /y/ or /œ/?

Comment: There is no denasalization in *il leur en a donné*.

Comment: @jlliagre, is this because the word "en" never denasalizes? Are there any words that end in "-en" that do?

Comment: As far as I know, words ending with a consonant followed by -en do not nasalize in the first place (e.g. *hymen*, *pollen*, *spécimen*) except *examen*, *réexamen* and *ben* (for *bien*) . The latter keep their nasalization and rhyme with -in, not with -an like *en* which has a unique pronunciation. Among them, only *ben* might trigger a liaison. Otherwise, with words ending with a vowel followed by -en (mostly are in -ien), the denasalization is optional. *Bien arrivé* can be pronounced \bjɛn‿aʁive\,\bjen‿aʁive\, \bjɛ̃n‿aʁive\ or \bjɛ̃n aʁive\ (no liaison) depending on the speaker.

Comment: @jlliagre "As far as I know, words ending with a consonant followed by -en do not nasalize in the first place [...]". Wow, I never realized this, I guess I had made a false generalization from non-final "en" and the one-word "en". Thanks for opening my eyes. I'll change the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, words ending with -un do not denasalize when they participate in a liaison, which is rare.

The liaison is mandatory with *un*, *aucun*, *commun*

> *Un avion* \ɛ̃n‿avjɔ̃\ or in a wide Paris area \œ̃n‿avjɔ̃\
>
> *D'un commun accord* \komɛ̃n‿akɔʁ\ or \komœ̃n‿akɔʁ\
>
> *Aucun artiste...* \okɛ̃n‿aʁtist\ or \okœ̃n‿aʁtist\

but forbidden with most if not all other words in -un like *chacun*, *embrun*, *importun*, *opportun*, *jeun*.

> *Chacun arrive...* \ʃakɛ̃ aʁiv\

Words ending with -um do not nasalize in the first place. They are pronounced \ -ɔm\ , e.g. *album* \albɔm\

There is a unique exception : *parfum* \parfɛ̃\ or \parfœ̃\ which never liaises.

The cases of denasalization in French seems to be limited to finals in [ɛ̃] and [ɔ̃].

> *Ancien ami* \ɛ̃sjɛ̃n‿ami\, \ɛ̃sjen‿ami\ or \ɛ̃sjɛn‿ami\
>
> *Son ami* \sɔ̃n‿ami\ or \sɔn‿ami\

Comment: Thanks! How about "brun"? I know it wouldn't usually cause liaison, but could it possibly come before a noun in archaic language or something?

Comment: I don't see any case where *brun* would cause a liaison.